# In C# how do I get the message from a WebException?

Tags: c#, exception

I have a C# application and a PHP API. When the API receives a bad request I return a 406 Not Acceptable error with a descriptive message of why the request was not acceptable.

When I catch the WebException in C# how to I get my message so I can get my descriptive message instead of "The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable." that is in WebException.Message

The response looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resultxmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <code>406</code>
    <message>
        <![CDATA[You just did something that is not acceptable.]]>
    </message>
    <errorsxsi:nil="true"/>
</result>
```

This is the C# with the WebException catch

```
HttpWebRequest _Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

_Request.Method = "PUT";
_Request.Timeout = 100000;
_Request.ContentType = "text/xml";

try
{
    return (HttpWebResponse)_Request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException _Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("WebException raised :" + _Exception.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
```

What should I replace _Exception.Message with?

Comment: Check to see if there is an inner exception that cause the web exception. That should have the error that cause the web error.

Comment: if there is an inner exception, throw the exception from web exception and catch it from inner exception